# Invalid data when querying Android SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with values like this:

```
_id, airportcode, lat, lan
1, AUS, 31.0672, 97.8289
...
```

When I open the database in SQLiteDatabase Browser and run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT _id, airportcode, lat, lon FROM latlon WHERE airportcode="AUS"
```

It returns:

```
    1, AUS, 31.0672, 97.8289
```

In my Android app I have this:

```
    public LatLonResult getLatLonFor(String airportCode){

    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.query(
            true, DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_AIRPORTCODE, KEY_LAT, KEY_LON},
            String.format("%s=\"%s\"", KEY_AIRPORTCODE, airportCode),
            null, null, null, null, null);

    LatLonResult result = null;
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        result = new LatLonResult();
        result.setAirportCode(mCursor.getString(
                mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_AIRPORTCODE)));

        result.setLat(mCursor.getDouble(
                mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LAT)));

        result.setLat(mCursor.getDouble(
                mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LON)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

LatLonResult is just getters/setters.

However when I run the previous code, result has the following values:

```
result.getAirportCode: AUS
result.getLat: 97.67
result.getLon: null
```

The latitude has the wrong value and longitude is null.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong here? If not, what other information can I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code listed you have:

```
    result.setLat(mCursor.getDouble(
            mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LAT)));

    result.setLat(mCursor.getDouble( //second call to setLat
            mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LON)));
```

I assume this should be

```
    result.setLat(mCursor.getDouble(
            mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LAT)));

    result.setLon(mCursor.getDouble(
            mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LON)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the column index is not always the same as the order of your select statment. When pulling data out of a cursor you should call [getColumnIndex](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) and pass the return value to the getDouble call.

Comment: I do have that in my code, I changed it when I started troubleshooting. I'll update the code above to fix this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The result columns are always guaranteed to be in the same order as in the `SELECT`.